# Torrent video player?

Tags: video, software-rec, bittorrent, media-player

Could you please suggest if there are any good torrent video players available?

I mean torrent clients which download last piece of video file, then sequentially from beginning and do not lock the file so that you can play it right away.

I remember some beta of uTorrent was working perfectly, but then they broken it somehow and I never managed to use it again. Any suggestions?

Comment: Downloading a file sequentially over bittorrent defeats the point, and I'm not sure it's possible to do anything more than 'prioritise'  linearity.

Comment: @Phoshi - Vuze is doing that just great ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Azureus](http://azureus.sourceforge.net/) (now apparently called Vuze) does this.

Comment: azureus vuze doesn't choose to download the torrent sequentially it just tries to play the partial file.....all players i have ever used do that part

Comment: Thank's that's perfect and even exceeds my expectations - even seeking works - it starts downloading from the point I've seekd and plays from the middle fine even while I have just 5% downloaded :-D

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of protocols that do this...but it is not built in to the torrent spec.  swarm does this.  torrent clients won't do it.  swarm is a video torrent streaming solution.

Comment: google swarm client

Answer (score 0):

BitComet has such a feature(right click on the torrent name in the list and select "Download for preview"), I do often use it when I want to watch the video while downloading it. It's a pity uTorrent doesn't have such an option

Answer (score 0):

Powder Player: http://powder.media/

Supports streaming torrents, downloads last piece of video file, then sequentially from beginning. Has advanced settings, finds subtitles by itself.

There's also Powder Web ( https://github.com/jaruba/PowderWeb ), which is not a player, but a full fledged torrent client with streaming capabilities, it can either stream to any video player of your choosing or to the browser.